# How do I join integers in path using os.path.join()

Tags: python

I have two integers, m and n

I tried:

> temp_mask_path = os.path.join(image_save_path, 'mask' + str(mi) + str(ni) + '.png')

I get this when I print temp_mask_path

> imagessavedhere\mask0-1.png

But I have to get

> imagessavedhere\mask01.png

without the  '-' sign

Can someone help?

Comment: perhaps `ni = -1`?

Comment: Yeah, let me check

Comment: Yep. Thanks. Silly mistake. I am new here, I guess this question needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle negative numbers, you could replace `'mask' + str(mi) + str(ni) + '.png'` with the following:

```py
f'mask{abs(mi)}{abs(ni)}.png'
```

It should do the trick.